# Question about grammatical name and its function

Tags: grammaticality

What is the grammatical name given to, and the function of, the part of the sentence below in bold?

> **Maneuvring a tanker** is likewise a daunting challenge.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is General Reference that OP's usage is a [simile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simile). As opposed to a [metaphor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/metaphor) which is much the same thing without using words like ***like***. Although note that [likewise](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likewise) is a single word, not two.

Comment: Thie is not really a simile at all, though it might have been mistaken for one before Andrew Leach clarified it (and FumbleFingers's comment did precede that).

Answer (score 6):

As Gary's Student has pointed out, in the simplified example

- ***Maneuvering the tanker*** is a challenge.

the subject of the sentence is *maneuvering the tanker*;
in order to be a subject, this must be a noun. But it doesn't **look** like a noun.
It looks exactly like a verb phrase, with a verb ***maneuvering***
and a direct object noun phrase ***the tanker***.

And that's what it is. A verb phrase, acting as a noun phrase. But not just any old verb phrase.
*Maneuvering the tanker* is a **[Gerund](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html)** verb phrase -- that's what the *-ing* suffix marks.
This verb phrase is all that's left of the subject [gerund complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf)

- *`Indef`'s maneuvering the tanker is a challenge for `Indef`*

after removing all the references to the indefinite subject
("`Indef`", the person who's doing the maneuvering and experiencing the challenge).
This has the effect of making the clause generic, true for any agent subject.

So, to answer your question about grammatical name and function:

1. *maneuvering the tanker* is a transitive verb phrase (verb + direct object)
2. *maneuvering the tanker* is a gerund verb phrase (with an *-ing* suffix)
3. *maneuvering the tanker* is a gerund clause (with a missing subject)
4. *maneuvering the tanker* is a complement clause (with a grammatical relation to the verb)
5. *maneuvering the tanker* is a gerund subject complement clause (subject of *be a challenge*)
6. *maneuvering the tanker* is a noun clause (with a missing subject)
7. *maneuvering the tanker* is a noun phrase (because it functions as the subject)

These are all true, simultaneously, depending on which aspect of the sentence you're talking about.

> **Note:**
>    - that a clause is any constituent with a subject and a verb
>    (though the subject may only be implied in context, as here),
>    - that a verb phrase is just a clause with a missing subject,
>    - that a clause can be the subject or the object of a verb
>   (and therefore a clause can itself be the subject, or object, of another clause), and
>    - that a noun phrase is anything that behaves like a noun in a clause.

Answer (score 3):

First let us simplify the sentence:

*Maneuvering the tanker is a challenge.*

We now see that the phrase "Maneuvering the tanker" is the **subject** of the sentence.  The phrase acts as a **noun** and may be termed a nominal phrase.  Since *maneuvering* is a gerund, it is also a gerund phrase.

Comment: The more precise term is _gerund phrase._

Comment: @BrianDonovan......Thanks!  I will perform an update.

Comment: There's lots more precision available for them as needs it.

Answer (score 0):

'Maneuvering a tanker' is  a nominal clause functioning as  the subject of the the verb ' is' . It is a nominal clause because , ' maneuvering '  is a verbal. Verbals are forms of the verb that functions in other word classes. In this regard , the 'ing' form of the verb  is a verbal, specifically a gerund, which in it self is a clause and it has the potential to function as the subject of a sentence.